# PHP Extract all text from html page

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I have been scratching my head over it for past 1 hour. Is there any reliable way to extract ONLY text

and nothing else (code,images,link,styles,script) from a html page. I am trying to extract all the text inside body of html document.

This includes paragraphs,plain text and tabular data..

So far I have tried `simplehtmldom` parser and also `file_get_contents` but both of them are not working. Here is code:

```
<?php

require_once "simple_html_dom.php";

function getplaintextintrofromhtml($html) {

    // Remove the HTML tags
    $html = strip_tags($html);

    // Convert HTML entities to single characters
    $html = html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    return $html;

}

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contempt');

echo getplaintextintrofromhtml($html);
?>
```

Here is screenshot of output:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-b63LoI1gSfaGhpR0NvdUtlbW8/edit?usp=drivesdk

As you can see it is displaying weird output and not even displaying whole page text

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php and strip_tags()

Comment: what are you trying to extract? its unclear. what should be the final output? the contents inside `<head></head>`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to accomplish: if you get the text, you'd get all the menus, titles etc concatenated? I'd say, make a small example with some input, and the desired output, and what you mean by "notworking". What is different from your expected output? Put some effort in both your project and your question. see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've played around with this and found that some info is in script tags which aren't being removed with `strip_tags` the other characters are ASCII and not UTF-8 so use the following to remove those chars as well: `iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $string)`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't why you think SimpleHTMLDOM doesn't work but you just have to use it properly, just target the body, then use the `->innertext` attribute:

```
function getplaintextintrofromhtml($url) {
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = file_get_html($url);
    // point to the body, then get the innertext
    $data = $html->find('body', 0)->innertext;
    return $data;
}

echo getplaintextintrofromhtml('http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contempt');
```

Answer (score 1):

i think  PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser is quickest and easy way to do that 
try
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
features
A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!
Require PHP 5+.
Supports invalid HTML.
Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.
Extract contents from HTML in a single line
```

Answer (score 0):

Html2Text is a good library just for that.

https://github.com/mtibben/html2text

Install using composer:

```
composer require html2text/html2text
```

Basic usage:

```
$html = new \Html2Text\Html2Text('Hello, &quot;<b>world</b>&quot;');

echo $html->getText();  // Hello, "WORLD"
```